# How to remove the schema Article that Yoast seo 11.x adds to my Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, schema, json-ld, yoast

Yoast SEO plugin adds to my Wordpress site Article schema automatically. Can I remove it, only "Article" (keep other schemas)?

I installed Yoast SEO 11.7 premium (Vietnamese). I tried the code below at file "function.php" in child theme, but failed

```
function bybe_remove_yoast_json($data){
    if ( (isset($data['@type'])) && ($data['@type'] == 'Article') ) {
        $data = array();
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wpseo_json_ld_output', 'bybe_remove_yoast_json', 10, 1);
```

Please help me. Thank you very much!